# High CPU usage in console application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to constantly wait for a key combination to be pressed in my console application, but the way I am currently doing it seems to use a lot of CPU while the process is running.

For such a basic task it feels like there should be a better way to do this, but I'm unsure of what that is, I profiled my application with dotTrace and found that the only hot spot was this code below.

[image]

```
while (true)
{
    if (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var input = Console.ReadKey(true);

    if (input.Modifiers != ConsoleModifiers.Control)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
    {
        Server?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are experiencing "busy waiting": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting

Comment: Doesn't `Console.ReadKey` block until there is a key available? I don't think you need your `if(!Console.KeyAvailable) continue;` block.

Comment: out of interest, which code editor you are using, if it is okay?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy For my IDE I'm using visual studio, but the image in the question is a snapshot of a C# profiler (dottrace).

Comment: @ropuxil aha, thank you :)

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Thanks for that, it took the CPU usage down from around 20-30% to 3%.

Comment: For some combinations Ctrl+KEY registers as normal key-press. But for some unknown reason Ctrl+S does not. Are you sure you want to wait for Ctrl+S and not for something else, that can be handled using plain ReadKey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are fine using standard Ctrl+C for exit instead of Ctrl+S you can use simple `ReadKey`. And make sure `TreatControlCAsInput` is set, oterwise, the application will just be killed.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     // important!!!
     Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

     while (true)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Use CTRL+C to exit");
        var input = Console.ReadKey();

        if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.C && input.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control)
        {
           break;
        }
     }

     // Cleanup
     // Server?.Dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of watching this in a loop, use the keypress event to check each time a key is pressed.

This means you only check once for each key press.

**Edit:**
I missed the console app part but you can read the line like this:

from: https://www.dotnetperls.com/console-readline

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        while (true) // Loop indefinitely
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter input:"); // Prompt
            string line = Console.ReadLine(); // Get string from user
            if (line == "exit") // Check string
            {
                break;
            }
            Console.Write("You typed "); // Report output
            Console.Write(line.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(" character(s)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how will you do that in console app?

Comment: There is no event in console applications, are you talking about something else? If so could you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

No busy waiting is needed. `Console.ReadKey()` will block until there is a key press available, with basically no CPU usage. Thus, you don't need to check `Console.KeyAvailable` over and over again.

```
while (true)
{
    // DO NOT INTERCEPT KEY PRESSES! 
    //IF CTRL+S IS FORWARDED TO THE CONSOLE APP, WEIRD THINGS WILL HAPPEN.
    var input = Console.ReadKey(false);

    if (input.Modifiers != ConsoleModifiers.Control)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
    {
        Server?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? For me (Win 10), Ctrl+S does not trigger ReadKey.

Comment: @Euphoric no, will check. If true, then OP has the general problem of not being able to read that key, regardless of waiting.

Comment: @Euphoric Interception was the problem. Setting it to `false` solves all problems. Before, `Ctrl+C` would also kill the program ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Thread.Sleep

```
 while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            if (!Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var input = Console.ReadKey(true);

            if (input.Modifiers != ConsoleModifiers.Control)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
            {
                Server?.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need this before finish Main(string[] args)

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
     //call method for daemon before while
     while (true)
     {
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
}
```